# Joining SQL Views with Missing Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, view

I have two views on two separate servers.

These views output the name, month, count

One view a person(Joe User) may have just July, August so it would show like this

```
Joe User July 19
Joe User August 28
```

The next view they may have some more

```
Joe User May 20
Joe User June 98
Joe User July 18
Joy User August 24
```

What I am trying to get the output to display is this.

```
Joe User January 0 0
Joe User February 0 0
Joe User March 0 0
Joe User April 0 0
Joe User May 20 0
Joe User June 98 0 
Joe User July 18 19
Joe User August 24 28
Joe User September 0 0
Joe User October 0 0
Joe User November 0 0
Joe User December 0 0
```

My question is how can I populate months even if they do not have values? Then join the values I do have.

Update:

With the examples below I get very similar results. Here is what I get when I try to run it without adding the name to WHERE.

```
Joe User April 65 518
Joe User April 87 518
Joe User April 52 518
Joe User April 3  518
```

This repeats with table values for 64 lines per month.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What SQL product/version   (SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL, etc.)

Comment: Maybe write 12 different `SELECT` queries, one for each month, and UNION them all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, number, '20010101')), 
       ISNULL(v2.[count], 0), ISNULL(v1.[count], 0)
FROM master..spt_values v LEFT JOIN view1 v1 ON DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, v.number, '20010101')) = v1.[month] AND v1.name = 'Joe User'
                          LEFT JOIN view2 v2 ON DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, v.number, '20010101')) = v2.[month] AND v2.name = 'Joe User'
WHERE v.type = 'P' AND v.number < 12
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33b94/1/0)

UPDATE

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT v1.name
 FROM view1 v1
 UNION
 SELECT v2.name
 FROM view2 v2
 ) u CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, number, '20010101')) AS [month], 
                         ISNULL(v2.[count], 0) AS [count1], ISNULL(v1.[count], 0) AS [count2]                       
                  FROM master..spt_values v 
                    LEFT JOIN view1 v1 ON DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, v.number, '20010101')) = v1.[month] AND v1.name = u.name
                    LEFT JOIN view2 v2 ON DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, v.number, '20010101')) = v2.[month] AND v2.name = u.name
                  WHERE v.type = 'P' AND v.number < 12
                  ) o
```

New Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33b94/2/0)

Comment: Tried this as well. The output is not the same. In your demo, add another user to the second table and give  him 24. Then run it again. It pulls a value that does not exist for him.

Comment: I add condition in JOIN operations;)

Comment: I can get it to work with 1 user. The problem is there are 200 users and I dont want to have to edit the query 200 times.

Comment: But sqlfiddle working without errors.!?!what error specifically

Comment: Ok, so I messed with it this morning and fixed the collation errors. This works perfect! I need to do some research on some of it but I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a date table, then `JOIN` your two tables. Otherwise, you can create one inside your query like this:

```
SELECT m.month, CASE WHEN c.ccount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.ccount END AS view2,
CASE WHEN b.ccount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.ccount END AS view1
FROM
(SELECT 'January' AS month
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'February'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'March'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'April'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'May'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'June'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'July'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'August'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'September'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'November'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'December') m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, month, ccount FROM view1 WHERE name = 'Joe') b ON b.month = m.month
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, month, ccount FROM view2 WHERE name = 'Joe') c ON c.month = m.month
```

**Result**

```
|     MONTH | VIEW2 | VIEW1 |
-----------------------------
|   January |     0 |     0 |
|  February |     0 |     0 |
|     March |     0 |     0 |
|     April |     0 |     0 |
|       May |    20 |     0 |
|      June |    98 |     0 |
|      July |    18 |    19 |
|    August |    24 |    28 |
| September |     0 |     0 |
|  November |     0 |     0 |
|  December |     0 |     0 |
```

Comment: This seems to be the right path. I tried it and its very close. The issue now is how can I run this for all 200 users without have to specify the name in the joins? Also for months where the user had nothing the name appears as null.

Comment: @JDRoberson does it work? Then what about this "I have two views on two separate servers."?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan If the servers are linked there is no need to open a new connection.

Comment: They are linked, I can get all the data, its just the output formatting thats the issue.

Comment: @JDRoberson OK, then my solution is redundant :) Then you no need to say about different server.

Answer (score 1):

First you must create linked server or use `OPENROWSET`.
Try this with `OPENROWSET`.

```
;WITH Months
AS
(
    SELECT 1 m, DATENAME(mm, '20000101') MN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m+1, DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(m, m, '20000101')) MN
    FROM Months
    WHERE m < 12
)
SELECT
   COALESCE(V1.nmae, V2.name) Name, 
   M.MN [Month], 
   ISNULL(V1.count, 0) Count1, 
   ISNULL(V2.count, 0) Count12 
FROM Months M
    LEFT JOIN ViewOnCurrentServer V1
        ON M.MN = V1.[month]
    LEFT JOIN
         OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=YouServerName;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                    'SELECT name, month, count
                     FROM DBName.SchemeName.ViewOnAnotherServer') V2
       ON M.MN = V2.[month]
WHERE COALESCE(V1.nmae, V2.name) = 'Joe User'
```

or if you use linked server then use:

```
;WITH Months
AS
(
    SELECT 1 m, DATENAME(mm, '20000101') MN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m+1, DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(m, m, '20000101')) MN
    FROM Months
    WHERE m < 12
)
SELECT
   COALESCE(V1.nmae, V2.name) Name, 
   M.MN [Month], 
   ISNULL(V1.count, 0) Count1, 
   ISNULL(V2.count, 0) Count12 
FROM Months M
    LEFT JOIN ViewOnCurrentServer V1
        ON M.MN = V1.[month]
    LEFT JOIN
         ViewOnLinkedServer V2
       ON M.MN = V2.[month]
WHERE COALESCE(V1.nmae, V2.name) = 'Joe User'
```

Comment: Trying this, they have different Collation so I am getting an error. Where in this statement would I put the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

Comment: Try this: `WHERE COALESCE(V1.nmae, V2.name) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT= 'Joe User' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`

Comment: I think you need add this in JOIN conditions too.

Comment: Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement.

Comment: Try this: `COALESCE(V1.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, V2.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)`

Comment: Ok getting close. Now I have 64 lines of each month for each user. Seems Column 2 is populating correctly, but Column 1 is repeating

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23523/discussion-between-jd-roberson-and-hamlet-hakobyan)